# Android 2.2 Emulator not working

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am creating an emulator but it is not starting.

I receive the following error;

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'Froyo'
```

> X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
>   Major opcode of failed request:  136 (GLX)
>     Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
>     Serial number of failed request:  12
>     Current serial number in output stream:  12

How do I fix this?

Comment: Try deleting and re-creating the emulator. Can you create emulators based on other SDK-versions without problems?

Answer (score 0):

just delete your .android folder in your path(like C:\Users\Abhinai.android) and open your avd manager and just try to create a new AVD its works fine

Comment: nothing happen ,it reamins the error,i can re -download but as a develeper need to know th reason thats all

Answer (score -1):

Have a look for (EE) in your /var/log/Xorg.0.log

There is something wrong with your opengl installation.  Possibly wrong versions of libraries and/or drivers.